# How to remove level shifts and pulses from time series?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am interested in describing seasonal patterns in several time series and then seeing if they are related. My approach is to fit regression models with an indicator variable for each season which estimates a separate intercept for each seasonal effect. However, one of the series I am looking at has a large level shift (i.e., jump) and another has a pulse (i.e., systematically higher level that returns to 'normal' after several observations). These components are causing the seasonal indicator models to fit poorly and are also obscuring the estimated seasonal effects. My question is how do I remove them? Differencing these series removes these parts, but it makes the so parameters unintuitive that it does not address my research question. That is, it makes the estimated parameters not based on the general series level but only relative to the prior value. I have tried to model them explicitly as interventions (i.e., 0 for before and after the pulse, while 1 during) and then working with the residuals. I have had limited success with this approach (it worked for the pulse well enough but not the level shift). Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can remove first deterministic effects via regression using dummies etc?

Next step would be to model residual series via ARIMA methods. Perhaps after that you use spectral domain methods for finding out seasonal frequencies in these residual series?